# is the DELL ULTRASHARP 2408WFP discontinued?

Tags: lcd

Can't find the DELL ULTRASHARP 2408WFP on dell's site anymore.

what was it replaced with?

Answer (score 1):

The 2408WFP is followed up by the U2410.
The old screen was an S-PVA panel by Samsung with standard sRGB gamut, the new one has a H-IPS panel by LG with wide gamut close to AdobeRGB.
The older had the better contrast, the new one has a shorter input-lag. I think it also came down a bit in price, as the IPS panels are slight cheaper than the PVA panels.

The looks are not that different, but you will see the new one has a much wider gamut, and thus bolder colours. The image will look different.

The old screen is on sale at a lot of third parties, and is still easy to get.

Comment: I have the U2410. I'm totally loving it. If I were you I wouldn't bother with the older model.

Answer (score 0):

still available in Europe (via DELL Ireland)

**[DELL ULTRASHARP 2408WFP](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=ie&l=en&s=dhs&cs=iedhs1&sku=147262)**

on the US website, this seems to be the the only 24" UltraSharp:

**[Dell UltraSharp  U2410](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Monitors/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-8277)**

... which is available in Europe too, 10% dearer than the 2408WFP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I looked into some more 2208's and they have some similar stuff available, but nothing with the same dimensions.

It is disappointing, because I bought two and was going to buy 4 more so my screens all match. Now I have to buy all six at once. Probably next year.